# Meteor and Video.js player loading issues

Tags: meteor, video.js, meteorite

I have probelm running video.js player.

First I put the `video.js` and `video-js.css` in `client/compatibility` folder so it will load first

Then in my client side html I write the following simple code,, It is not working

```
          <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered"
                  controls  width="640" height="264"
                  poster="{{video.thumbs}}"
                  data-setup='{"controls": true, "autoplay": true,"techOrder":["flash", "html5"],preload="auto"}'>
                 <source  type='video/flv' src="{{uurl}}" />
            </video>
```

There are no issues with the template helpers they are working fine but

The problem is with the video.js player , It is not loading.

Anyone tried this before? Struck here, Any help appreciated

**UPDATE:**

dynamic loading solution working fine for me but
when I click on a video it redirects to **/video/:_id/:_slug** page with subscribing to single video but when I go back to the home page and again click on another video, this time video player is not initializing again

**Code**

when onclick on video:

```
'click .videothumb > a':function(e,t){
        Session.set("url",e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-url"));
        var url=e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-url");
        var title=e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-title");
        var cid=e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-id");
        Meteor.call("videoData",url,function(er,da){
            console.log(cid);
            Session.set('vurl',da);
            Router.go("video",{_id:cid,slug:title});
        });
    }
```

**routing**

```
this.route("video",{
          path:'/video/:_id/:slug',
           waitOn: function() {
            // return Meteor.subscribe('singleVideo', this.params._id);
          },
          onBeforeAction: function () {

          },
          data:function(){
                Session.set("currentVideoId",this.params._id);
                var video;
                video= Videos.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
                return {
                  video:video
                };
          }
    });
```

rendered function:

```
Template.video.rendered=function(){
        var id=Session.get("currentVideoId");
        Meteor.call("incViews",id,function(e,d){
            console.log("view added");
        });
        videojs("videoId",{"controls": true, "autoplay": false,"techOrder":["html5","flash"],preload:"auto"},function(){ 
          // Player (this) is initialized and ready. 
          **console.log("videojs initialized");**
          console.log(this)   ;
        } 
      );
};
```

that console "videojs initialized" is loging when only first when I route the video page

from next routing(when I click video thumbnail on homepage)The log functions is not loggind(means player is not initializing)

Any suggestions to make it work better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the time videojs script is initialized there is no template rendered, you need to manually initialize videojs player.

**tpl1.html**:

```
<template name="tpl1">
  <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered"
              controls  width="640" height="264"
              poster="{{video.thumbs}}">
     <source  type='video/flv' src="{{uurl}}" />
  </video>
</template>
```

**tpl1.js**:

```
Template.tpl1.rendered = function(){
  videojs(
    "example_video_1",
    {"controls": true, "autoplay": true,"techOrder":["flash", "html5"],preload="auto"},
    function(){           // Player (this) is initialized and ready.        } 
  );
})
```

Please read documentation of Video.js: 
["Alternative Setup for Dynamically Loaded HTML"](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/guides/setup.md)

Comment: Working fine,updated the question,any suggestions pls?

Answer (score 1):

I implemented it in my project w/o using Blaze but using a lower-level Tracker dependencies. When the Template is rendered, I would dynamically start the player and then have a reactive data-source of the current position that I can control: https://github.com/Slava/talk-player/blob/master/client/player.js

Comment: Thx for your time slava,updated the question, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Meteor 1.6.1.1.

template html

```
<template name="tebVideo">
  <video class="video-js">
    <source src="{{src}}" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</template>
```

template js

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import 'video.js/dist/video-js.css';
import videojs from 'video.js';
import './video.html';

// prevent analytics
window.HELP_IMPROVE_VIDEOJS = false;

// helper for local dev vs product cdn 
const envUrl = (localPath, fileName) => {
  if (Meteor.isProduction) {
    return Meteor.settings.public.host.cdnUrl+'/'+fileName;
  }
  else {
    return localPath+fileName;
  }
};

Template.tebVideo.onRendered(() => {
  const instance = Template.instance();
  const video = videojs(document.querySelector('.video-js'),
    {
      controls: true,
      autoplay: false,
      preload: 'auto',
      width: 854,
      height: 480,
      aspectRatio: "16:9",
      poster: envUrl('/images/', instance.data.poster),
      function() {
        Log.log(['debug', 'video'], 'Video loaded ok');
      }
    }
  );
});

Template.tebVideo.helpers({
  src() {
    const instance = Template.instance();
    return envUrl('/videos/', instance.data.src);
  }
});
```

show it

```
{{>tebVideo poster="three_robots.png" src="how-knowledge-automation-works.mp4"}}
```